Why do I get this error when I try to set my powershell terminal title in my ps1 script?
I have a .ps1 script that opens multiple powershell terminals and in each one it starts a nodejs application. In order to make it easier to tell which terminal corresponds to which node application, I want to set the title of the terminal. I do so with $host.ui.RawUI.WindowTitle = "my application". Here is a sample of the script:
start powershell {
    $host.ui.RawUI.WindowTitle = "application 1"
    cd application1\backend
    npm install
    npm run build
    npm run start
    Read-Host
}

start powershell {
    $host.ui.RawUI.WindowTitle = "application 2"
    cd application2\backend
    npm install
    npm run build
    npm run start
    Read-Host
}

start powershell {
    $host.ui.RawUI.WindowTitle = "application 3"
    cd application3\backend
    npm install
    npm run build
    npm run start
    Read-Host
}
...

There are more than 3 such blocks in the script, but you get the point.
The problem is I get this error in the terminal:

application : The term 'application' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:3 char:31

$host.UI.RawUI.WindowTitle = application 1

                          ~~~~~~~~~~~


CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (application:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException




I know $host.UI.RawUI.WindowTitle = "application 1" works from the terminal prompt. Why doesn't it work in a script?

You code start powershell {...} is being converted to Start-Process -FilePath "powershell" -ArgumentList {...}, which is problematic due to ArgumentList being defined as [string[]].  Not 100% clear on what is happening in the conversion of a scriptblock to a string, but it appears the double quotes are getting stripped out in the process.

@Darin, stringifying a script block yields its content verbatim, so no stripping happens there. The " stripping happens in the powershell.exe call: when you pass code to the -Command (-c) parameter (which is implied), " chars. are assumed to have purely syntactic function on the command line and are stripped during initial parsing. Escaping them as \" prevents that - see my answer for details.

@mklement0, thank you for the explanation!  Correct me if I'm wrong on this, but I'm thinking this really more of an issue with Windows itself and how arguments are passed to any exe, and not just an issue with PowerShell.

@Darin: Ultimately (and unfortunately), every CLI in Windows is free to make up its own rules when it comes to parsing its process command line (a concept that doesn't even exist in the Unix world, where arguments are passed as an array of verbatim strings). PowerShell decided to strip unescaped " characters from a -Command argument before interpreting the result as PowerShell code, though it could equally have decided to retain them; e.g., while powershell.exe -File some.ps1 "quoted argument" works fine, powershell.exe -Command Write-Output "quoted argument" does not.

@Darin: That said, retaining them would have required custom parsing, because the standard argument parsing offered by (ultimately) the C runtime (and similarly the one offered by the WinAPI) indeed strips unescaped " while splitting the process command line into tokens. Also, if you pass all the code inside an enclosing "..." string (from outside PS) - which is more robust when calling from cmd.exe - the need for escaping embedded "  chars. is obvious: powershell.exe -Command "Write-Output \"quoted argument\"". Note that \"-escaping can still break in cmd.exe / batch files.

@mklement0, thank you for detailed explanation.  You are bringing back bad memories of writing a batch scripts that passed multiple double quotes, each escaped in a different way depending on the context.

@Darin: . Yes, quoting (escaping) hell is real on Windows. With respect to robustly calling the PowerShell CLI, especially from cmd.exe / batch files, I've tried to provide guidance in the bottom section of this answer.


Passing a script block ({ ... }) as a (positionally implied) -ArgumentList argument to Start-Process (one of whose built-in aliases is start) technically works, but is limiting and obscures what's actually happening, so it is best avoided:

Because the -ArgumentList parameter is [string[]]-typed, the script block is stringified, meaning that its verbatim content (sans { and }) is passed.

Notably, this implies that you cannot reference the caller's variables in your argument, and it may lead you to think that there are no escaping requirements (see next point).


Aside from that, your problem is that you neglected to escape " characters as \", which is required in order to preserve them in code passed to the (implied) -Command (c) parameter of powershell.exe, the Windows PowerShell CLI.

See this answer for background information.

Also note that pwsh.exe, the PowerShell (Core) 7 CLI, defaults to the -File parameter, necessitating explicit use of -Command (-c) in order to pass PowerShell code.



Therefore, it is better to use a here-string, with the required escaping:
# Note: Short for:
#   Start-Process -FilePath powershell -ArgumentList @'...
start powershell @'
    $host.ui.RawUI.WindowTitle = \"application 1\"
    cd application1\backend
    npm install
    npm run build
    npm run start
    Read-Host
'@

Note:

Because ' characters have no syntactic function on the PowerShell process command line, they do not require escaping, so you can alternatively use embedded '...' quoting as shown in Keith Langmead's answer - however, '...' only works if the embedded string literal is meant to be a verbatim string rather than an expandable (interpolating) one (which requires "...").

Because no up-front string interpolation is required in your case (since you're not referencing the caller's variables), the above uses the verbatim here-string variant (@'<newline>...<newline>'@);  use the expandable form  (@"<newline>...<newline>"@) if caller-variable values must be referenced.



Enclose the title in single quotes rather than double. Eg :
start powershell {
    $host.ui.RawUI.WindowTitle = 'application 1'
    cd application1\backend
    npm install
    npm run build
    npm run start
    Read-Host
}

